# how to pass bound value to custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a directive something like this

```
<input ng-model="service" check-service="{{items}}" />
```

so every time value is modified in this input, I want to get latest value of whatever object is bound inside check-service i.e. latest value of items. I have basic directive like this but not sure how can I get latest value

```
.directive('checkService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newVal) {
                // how to get latest value of {{items}} here?
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$observe` property for this one.For that please checked this example. You will get better idea.
Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/Shivali/86upsdr0/

Hope this might be helpful to you!!

Comment: No I am not passing same value service in checkService. Inside checkService it bounds to different object

Comment: In short everytime when mode of this input is changed I want to retrieve the latest value of items